# How does google play music hides stream requests?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, google-play, google-chrome-devtools

When playing media from https://play.google.com/music/listen using chrome, in Dev Tools Network page there is no request for the stream. All other requests are visible.

When opened in Firefox, I see all requests including  chrome-hidden one `/videoplayback?...` with the stream.

In Firefox, requests seems  to be initiated via flash (if disabled, app fails play any stream).

In Chrome though, if you disable all plugins (**no flash** at all, no native client, etc.) you can still play streams, but they are somehow hidden in DevTools network tab. 
The question is - what the heck is going on?

**How does this pure web-app hides selected requests from dev tools?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome all Google Play Music `audio/mpeg` requests are done via [Google Play Music extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-play-music/icppfcnhkcmnfdhfhphakoifcfokfdhg).

If you inspect `background.js` of this extension you can see all streams requests.